# Dataframe column not converting to date after groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a dataset in which there are few columns. In the one column is of date. Date contains mixed format for date (both 01 and 1) and year(both 2020 and 20).

I wanted to group data based on date and merge the content of other columns so I used this:

```
covid_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(covid_df['Date'],format="%d/%m/%y").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
covid_df=covid_df.groupby('Date').agg(lambda col: col.tolist()).reset_index()
```

Now, that I have what I wanted I checked the columns data type again and found that now date column is again having object data type which means a string. So I converted my data frame one more time and sort it based on date column and do a tail operation. But sort is not happening correctly:

```
covid_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(covid_df['Date'],format="%d/%m/%y").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
covid_df.sort_values(by='Date')
print(covid_df.tail(10))
```

Output:

```
'
'
'
118  30/04/20  ...  [33, 1403, 1, 42, 403, 56, 38, 3439, 7, 4082, ...
119  30/05/20  ...  [33, 3436, 3, 1024, 3376, 289, 415, 2, 17386, ...
120  31/01/20  ...                                                [1]
121  31/03/20  ...  [40, 10, 15, 13, 8, 97, 5, 73, 40, 3, 54, 83, ...

[10 rows x 5 columns]
```

You can clearly see the date is not in sorted order.

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(covid_df['Date'],format="%d/%m/%y").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y")` converts it to a datetime and then back to a string.

Comment: I thought strftime is used for reformatting the values but the data type remains date time only. Thanks for clearing the confusion

Comment: In that case if I want to change the format but want it to remain of date time format ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the

```
covid_df.sort_values(by='Date')
```

creates a copy of your dataframe, but not saving it. So in order to do that, you should probably use

```
covid_df = covid_df.sort_values(by='Date')
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Trenton,

`pd.to_datetime(covid_df['Date'],format="%d/%m/%y").dt.strftime("%d/%m/%y")` converts it to a datetime and then back to a string